How to set Firebase Realtime Database rules for reading "mention" from any user?
I'm working on setting up Firebase Realtime Database rules, and I want to allow any authenticated user to read the mention node from any other user's data. However, I'm not sure if my current setup is correct.
Here are my current rules:
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
            "mention": {
                ".read": "true",
                ".write": "auth.uid == null"
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is my current code:
public void checkMention(String mention, MentionListener mentionListener) {
    database.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String userMention = userSnapshot.child("mention").getValue(String.class);
                if (userMention != null && userMention.equals(mention)) {
                    if (mentionListener != null) {
                        mentionListener.onMentionData(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mentionListener != null) {
                mentionListener.onMentionData(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

MainActivity Dialog:
private void openDialogUpdate() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
    DialogUpdateBinding updateBinding = DialogUpdateBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setView(updateBinding.getRoot()).create();

    TextInputLayout usernameInput = updateBinding.usernameInput;
    TextInputEditText inputUsername = updateBinding.inputUsername;
    MaterialButton buttonUpdate = updateBinding.buttonUpdate;

    inputUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mentionCheckRunnable != null) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(mentionCheckRunnable);
            }
            mentionCheckRunnable = () -> {
                String mention = "@" + s.toString().trim().replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase();
                if (!mention.equals("@")) {
                    accountFirebase.checkMention(mention, exists -> {
                        if (exists) {
                            usernameInput.setError(getString(R.string.unavailable_mention));
                        } else {
                            usernameInput.setHelperText(getString(R.string.available_mention));
                            usernameInput.setError(null);
                        }
                    });
                }
                buttonUpdate.setText(mention);
            };
            handler.postDelayed(mentionCheckRunnable, 1500);
        }
    });
    
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (inputUsername.getText() != null) {
            String uid = accountFirebase.getUid();
            String username = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!username.isEmpty() && username.length() > 8) {
                accountFirebase.updateUsername(username, uid).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } else if (!username.isEmpty() && username.length() < 8) {
                showMessage(updateBinding.getRoot(), getString(R.string.username_too_short));
            } else {
                showMessage(updateBinding.getRoot(), getString(R.string.username_empty));
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

My goal:

When the user creates an account, he goes to the MainActivity, and a dialog opens for him to update his name!

When the user starts typing, checkMention() should search all the users' mentions to see if the same one already exists.

Making it so that the user can only update his name if the mention doesn't exist yet!


Even though my dialog is not finished yet, the current problem is only when reading all user mentions, the toast returns "permission denied" in checkMention().
I hope all users' mention node is public.

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.

You seem think that that Firebase security rules filter the data on the server, which is not what they do. Instead, Firebase merely ensures that any data that your code/client tries to access matches with the rules you've set.
Knowing that, let's have a look at this code:
database.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { ... }

This tries to read the data from /users. Firebase checks the security rules, and see that there is no rule to allow reading from /users, so it rejects the operation.
This is a pretty common mistake, so I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on rules are not filters.
Using query based rules sometimes allows you to implement secure filtering, but I don't think that'll work here.
If you want to create a public node and a secured node, you'll need to split them at a higher level. For example:
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            },
        },
        "mentions": {
            ".read": "true",
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "auth.uid == null"
            },
        }

    }
}

For more examples of this, see:

Firebase: How to structure public/private user data
How to create public/private user profile with Firebase security rules?
Firebase Security Rules: Public vs. Private Data

